# to carry out a full analysis

Tags: prepositions

a. I am sending you these books to learn quantum mechanics.

b. I am sending you these books to learn quantum mechanics with.

======================================

c. The samples were sent to the lab to carry out a full analysis.

d. The samples were sent to the lab to carry out a full analysis on.

Which of the above are grammatically correct?

I know that the rule that sentences should not end with prepositions is not a valid rule.

I think both 'a' and 'b' work. 'With' is implied in (a). I have doubts about 'c'. I think we need the 'on'.

Comment: These sentences might well be used in casual speech, but they could be better expressed.  The books are not going to learn, nor the samples carry out the analysis. "I am sending these books for you to learn quantum mechanics" (I don't think a preposition is necessary here). "The samples were sent to the lab for a full analysis to be carried out" (you could add "on them" if you wanted).

Comment: No, because we cannot tell who is learning it. I'm sending you these books **so you can learn x or for you to learn x**.

Answer (score -1):

All of the sentences here are quite ambiguous. I’ll break each of them down.

> I am sending you these books to learn quantum mechanics.

It is unclear who is learning quantum mechanics, you or the speaker. In the case of the latter, it seems that they’re sending you books so that *they* can learn quantum mechanics, which obviously doesn’t make much sense.

> I am sending you these books to learn quantum mechanics with.

Better, but still unclear: are the books also learning quantum mechanics with you? Are the books your “study buddy”?

> The samples were sent to the lab to carry out a full analysis.

This one in particular is a big no-no, as this one directly conveys that the samples are going to conduct an analysis, and it’s not even clear what they’re going to analyze.

> The samples were sent to the lab to carry out a full analysis on.

Ambiguous because it’s unclear whether the analysis is going to be *on the samples*, or if the samples are mini scientists going to conduct an analysis on…something you forget to mention.

A better way to express each sentence would be as follows:

> I am sending you these books so you can learn quantum mechanics.
>
> The samples were sent to the lab to undergo a full analysis.

Comment: "The samples were sent to the lab to carry out a full analysis on" is not ambiguous, and is fairly idiomatic. There's only one reason you'd send samples to a lab, and that is to be analyzed. Some of this answer is sensible but you're bizarrely over-reaching there.

Comment: @StuartF Obviously, context makes this much easier to understand. Context tends to do that. But grammatically, it is ambiguous. That is, syntactically the sentence is imperfect, but pragmatically, most people would know what you mean. And some of the sentences technically work, but are fairly unusual sentence structures, and thus not ideal, at least imo.